# C++ issue with LZW decoding

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing a LZW algorithm and I'm having trouble with decoding the encoded file. The encoding function works fine,the issues is as far as I know in the building of the dictionary in the decoding function. 
Edit: The size of the decoding dictionary is for 1 bigger than the encoding dictionary. Also the decoding dictionary doesn't seem to contain any string value that has more than 2 characters. For testing I used a .txt file of Alice in wonderland and the first few words are ok but after that everything goes wrong

My encoding function:

```
void encode(char* path, int vel_s){
    unordered_map<string,int>dict; //dictionary
    int bit_size = ceil(log2(vel_s + 1)); //size of codes - x bits
    //init dictionary
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        string k = "";
        k.push_back((unsigned char)i);
        dict[k] = i;
    }
    int count = 256, maxVel = pow(2, bit_size); //counter and max value in bits
    BinReader reader(path);//text to encodede
    BinWriter writer("out.bin");//output file
    string P = "";
    P.push_back(reader.readByte());//read first char
    while(!reader.f.eof()){
        char C = reader.readByte(); //read next char
        if(dict.find(P + C) != dict.end()){ //if in dictionary
            P+=C;
        }else{ //if not in dictionary
            if(count >= maxVel){
                count = 0;
            }
            int out = dict[P]; //int code of P
            string binString = toBinary(out, bit_size); //binary value of out
            for(int i = 0; i<binString.size();i++){ //write bits
                if(binString[i]=='1'){
                    writer.writeBit(true);
                }else{
                    writer.writeBit(false);
                }
            }
            dict[P + C] = count; //write P+C to dictionary
            count++;
            P = C; //overwrite P
        }
    }
    //write last output
    int out = dict[P];
    string binString = toBinary(out, bit_size);
    for(int i = 0; i<binString.size();i++){
        if(binString[i]=='1'){
            writer.writeBit(true);
        }else{
            writer.writeBit(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the decoding function:

```
void decompress(char* path, int vel_s){//file path + dictionary max size
    unordered_map<int,string>dict; //dictionary
    int bit_size = ceil(log2(vel_s + 1));//max number of bits in code
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){ //init dictionary
        dict[i] = (unsigned char) i;
    }
    int count = 256; //counter
    vector<bool>B;
    BinWriter writer("out_d.txt"); //output file
    BinReader reader(path); //input file
    int newI, oldI; //new and old value
    for(int i = 0; i < bit_size; i++){ //read code from encoded file of size bit_size
        B.push_back(reader.readBit());
    }
    oldI = convertToInt(B); //convert to integer
    string S = dict[oldI]; //String is dictionary value of old value
    writer.writeByte(S[0]); //write first letter
    string C = ""; //init C
     C =S[0]; //C is first character of S
    int maxVel = pow(2, bit_size); //max value of encoded code
    while(!reader.f.eof()){
        B.clear();//clear vector B for reading bits
        for(int i = 0; i < bit_size; i++){
            B.push_back(reader.readBit());//read next code
        }
        newI = convertToInt(B); //convert bits to int
        if(dict.find(newI) == dict.end()){ //if new value not in dictionary
            S = dict[oldI]; //S is value of old code
            S += C; //concat C to S
        }else{
            S = dict[newI]; //S is value of new code
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < S.size(); k++){ //write S to file
            writer.writeByte(S[k]);
        }
        C = "";
        C += S[0]; //C is first character of S
        dict[count] = dict[oldI] + C; //new input in dictionary
        count++;
        oldI = newI; //old value is new value
    }
```

And the toBinary() and convertToInt() functions that I use for help

```
string toBinary(int x, int l){
    string temp;
    while(x!=0){
        temp =(x%2==0 ? "0":"1")+temp;
        x/=2;
    }
    while(temp.length() != l){
        temp = "0"+temp;
    }
    return temp;
}


int convertToInt(vector<bool>B){
    int power= B.size()-1,res= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < B.size(); i++){
        if(B[i]){
            res+=pow(2, power);
        }
        power--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ***issues is as far as I know in the building of the dictionary in the decoding function*** From your question I am not sure what issue you are having. You probably should explain what you found when you stepped through the code line by line with your debugger so that you can narrow the issue down.

Comment: Time to learn to use the debugger.  There is really no way to not use it, given the code you've attempted to write.  Also, I highly doubt you need to use floating-point functions such as `pow` and `log2`.  You're risking round-off issues by using these functions.

Comment: dictionary sizes MUST BE THE SAME !, if your dictionary have only your alphabet  and not 2,3 or more "char" variations then your LZW does not work (however your decoding code looks it stores the variations). Take a look at this: [LZW Decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62100123/2521214) it might help your with debugging a lot. I do not see clearing your dictionary anywhere... you know the size is constant not dynamic ...