# Compressing a vector of positive integers (int32) that have a specific order

Tags: algorithm, integer, compression, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to compress long vectors (their size ranges from 1 to 100 million elements). The vectors have positive integers with values ranging from 0 to 1 or 100 million (depending on the vector size). Hence, I'm using 32 bit integers to encompass the large numbers but that consumes too much storage.
The vectors have the following characteristic features:

1. All values are positive integers. Their range grows as the vector size grows.
2. Values are increasing but smaller numbers do intervene frequently (see the figure below).
3. None of the values before a specific index are larger than that index (Index starts at zero). For instance, none of the values that occur before the index of 6 are larger than 6. However, smaller values may repeat after that index. This holds true for the entire array.
4. I'm usually dealing with very long arrays. Hence, as the array length passes 1 million elements, the upcoming numbers are mostly large numbers mixed with previous reoccurring numbers. Shorter numbers usually re-occur more than larger numbers. New Larger numbers are added to the array as you pass through it.

Here is a sample of the values in the array: {initial padding..., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 10, ... later..., 1110, 11, 1597, 1545, 1392, 326, 1371, 1788, 541,...}

Here is a plot of a part of the vector:
[image: Here is a plot of a part of the vector:]

**What do I want?** :
Because I'm using 32 bit integers this is wasting a lot of memory since smaller numbers that can be represented with less than 32 bit do repeat too. I want to compress this vector maximally to save memory (Ideally, by a factor of 3 because only a reduction by that amount or more will meet our needs!). What is the best compression algorithm to achieve that? Or is there away to take advantage of the array's characteristic features described above to reversibly convert the numbers in that array to 8 bit integers?

**Things that I have tried or considered**:

1. Delta encoding: This doesn't work here because the vector is not always increasing.
2. Huffman coding: Does not seem to help here since the range of unique numbers in the array is quite large, hence, the encoding table will be a large overhead.
3. Using variable Int encoding. i.e using 8 bit integers for smaller numbers and 16 bit for larger ones...etc. This has reduced the vector size to size*0.7 (not satisfactory since it doesn't take advantage of the specific characteristics described above)
4. I'm not quite sure if this method described in the following link is applicable to my data: http://ygdes.com/ddj-3r/ddj-3r_compact.html
   I don't quite understand the method but it gives me the encouragement to try similar things because I think there is some order in the data that can be taken to its advantage.
   For example, I tried to reassign any number(n) larger than 255 to n-255 so that I can keep the integers in 8 bit realm because I know that no number is larger than 255 before that index. However, I'm not able to distinguish the reassigned numbers with the repeated numbers... so this idea doesn't work unless doing some more tricks to reverse the re-assignments...

Here is the link to the fist 24000 elements of the data for those interested:
[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vIUt75A1mer2Mmz3CBYvc7wGr4SvaBwf/view?usp=sharing)

Any advice or suggestions are deeply appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit1:**

Here is a plot of the data after delta encoding. As you can see, it doesn't reduce the range!
[image: delta encoded]

**Edit2:**

I was hoping that I could find a pattern in the data that allows me to reversibly change the 32-bit vector to a single 8-bit vector but this seems very unlikely.
I have tried to decompose the 32-bit vector to 4 x 8-bit vectors, hoping that the decomposed vectors lend themselves to compression better.
Below are plots for the 4 vectors. Now their ranges are from 0-255.
What I did was to recursively divide each element in the vectors by 255 and store the reminder into another vector. To reconstruct the original array all I need to do is: ( ( (vec4*255) + vec3 )*255 + vec2 ) *255 + vec1...

[image: decomposed arrays]

As you can see, the last vector is all zeros for the current shown length of the data.. in fact, this should be zeros all the way to 2^24th element. This will be a 25% reduction if my total vector length was less than 16 million elements but since I'm dealing with much longer vectors this has a much smaller impact.
More importantly, the third vector seems also to have some compressible features as its values do increase by 1 after each 65,535 steps.
It does seem that now I can benefit from Huffman coding or variable bit encoding as suggested. Any suggestions that allows me to maximally compress this data are deeply appreciated.
Here I attached a bigger sample of the data if anyone is interested:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10wO3-1j3NkQbaKTcr0nl55bOH9P-G1Uu/view?usp=sharing

**Edit3:**

I'm really thankful for all the given answers. I've learnt a lot from them. For those of you who are interested to tinker with a larger set of the data the following link has 11 million elements of a similar dataset  (zipped 33MB)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aohfu6II6OdN-CqnDll7DeHPgEDLMPjP/view

Once you unzip the data, you can use the following C++ snippet to read the data into a vector<int32_t>

```
    const char* path = "path_to\compression_int32.txt";
    std::vector<int32_t> newVector{};
    std::ifstream ifs(path, std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::istream_iterator<int32_t> iter{ ifs };
    std::istream_iterator<int32_t> end{};
    std::copy(iter, end, std::back_inserter(newVector));
```

Comment: Delta encoding can still work if you allow negative deltas

Comment: I tried Delta encoding. It doesn't reduce the range of the numbers! i.e if the range is 0-to 1million after delta encoding the range becomes -500,000 to 500,000. This is not quite helpful here.

Comment: That's a shame. The other tricks that I know of are much more complicated, requiring explicit modeling of the probability distribution. Except bit-slicing, but I tried that on your data and it didn't work that well (it does take advantage of the limited range, but so does almost anything else, and it takes *some* advantage of the order)

Comment: Your data sample starts with `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 6, 6, 6, 20, 160,`. The presence of `160` at index `30` doesn't go well with the Feature Number Three.

Comment: @user58697 Thanks for the notice. Actually, the data starts with 159 zeros which for some reason didn't copy to the file that I put here. Now, I have fixed it. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: How about interpreting your data as Bytes and apply Huffman on that or LZW ... or use variable bit encoding stream (like in GIF) just like Mark Adler suggest in his answer

Comment: @Spektre, I have now decomposed the 32-bit vector into 4xbyte vectors. It shows some interesting features which, I think, can be compressed using Huffman. Please see my edit for more details.

Comment: Using the variable length approach in my answer, you can compress the 300,000 32-bit values to 0.539 of the original size. I'm not seeing any hope in your plots of the four bytes to do better than that. 0.539 almost removes vec3 and vec4.

Comment: @MarkAdler yes huffman encoding is near 54% too have added answer with some details on LZW and Huffman ...

Comment: Actually, I'm hoping for a compression by a factor of 3 or more (Not sure if that is possible but my needs do require this amount of compression!). Also, please keep in mind that I'm usually dealing with arrays that have more than million elements. The later parts of the data I posted with this question are the ones that dominate. i.e what comes after the 300,000th element are mostly large numbers mixed with previous re-occurring smaller numbers.

Comment: @user3134575 hmm without more info about the data I doubt you will get better than 2x and the bigger data you got the worse it will get... how is the data created, what it represents? I would try to search for way to separate the big values from the small however if the occurrence is too random then you out of luck unless some other property can be exploited.

Comment: Unless there is something amazing in the pattern of these numbers that you are not telling us, there is no way that you will get anywhere near a factor of three, or even two, for 100,000,000 values.

Comment: Why is the maximum value in your 100,000,000 numbers only a third of that length? In both of the examples you gave, the maximum value is very close to the length. (24950 for the length 24977 sequence, and 650468 for the length 650657 sequence.)

Comment: @MarkAdler Youre right its not a triangle and with increasing size its getting worse,  100 000 000 * 32 bit is encoded as 77.056% of the original size.  2^29 x 32bit is encoded as 84.375% size

Comment: @Spektre what I understood from MarkAdler's plot (in his posted answer) is as the values increase, the compression gain from variable bit-width based on index diminishes (so this approach would be very useful for smaller 32-bit sized arrays). As for your questions about the data and why is the max value is much less than the length of the array for 100mil, I'll try to find out why this is the case but I do think the newer values added less frequently to the array as its size grows.

Comment: What are constraints on runtime. Obviously if you don't care about runtime you could do a lot more than if you do.

Comment: @ldog no constraints on runtime. I just care about the maximum possible compression for this data.

Comment: By the way, your Property #3 as written is ambiguous, and I think not as strict as you intended. It is ambiguous because you do not state the origin of the index. Does it start at 0 or 1?

Comment: Property #3 is not as strict as your examples for either choice of index. In all of the examples, including "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 9, 1, 10", the value is <= the index if the index starts at 0, or < index if the index starts at 1.  "none of the values that occur before the index of 6 are larger than 6" would permit 6 at index 5. However the rule implied by your examples would permit at most 5 at index 5 for origin 0, or 4 at index 5 for origin 1.

Comment: @user3134575 Do you have a larger sample of data than compression2.txt that you can share? The answer I posted seems to scale close to its theoretical limit, and I wanted to see if it does so with say 1 million data samples, which should lend more confidence to the approach.

Comment: Or better yet, 10 million. 1 million is not much more than the already-provided 650,000. Ideally it would be provided in binary to keep the size reasonable. Four bytes per value. Or even three bytes per value if you like, for less than 16.7 million values.

Comment: @MarkAdler The values should not be larger than their indices. If they are, then this means there is some shifting or padding errors which I need to check. As requested, I have now provided around 11 million elements of a similar data (The Link at the end of my post - Edit3). The data follows the same pattern as before except this time there is an initial padding of -1s instead of 0s (the initial padding is too small compared to the size of the vector, hence, it is not important and it will be discarded anyway. All other values are positive)

Comment: @MarkAdler The origin of the index is 0 which starts at the very beginning of the file. And  also "None of the values before a specific index are larger than that index" should be correct too. i.e for e.g. you shouldn't find value 30 at index number 30, and all values before that index should be less than 30. A value like 30 may or may not appear after index number 30. From what I noticed, the smaller values do re-occur more frequently than the larger values.

Comment: As I said, it is not _as strict_ as your examples. That in fact _means_ that it is correct, but something more constraining is also correct. At least as evidenced by your examples. Do you not know for a fact what the third property is, or even if it is a property at all? Are you just determining this empirically? What is this data exactly? Also you still have not updated the question with the fact that you are considering the index to start at zero.

Comment: @MarkAdler  I have now added that index starts at zero. I have described the data empirically, I might have described it poorly or in a confusing way (I'm not a native speaker). Please feel free to suggest me a better description or if you can Edit my question, please feel free to edit it so that it will read clearer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your English is fine.

Comment: Again for the large set you provided, the largest value is very nearly the number of values. In this case the largest value is 11,590,199 out of 11,590,255 values. Still wondering why your >100,000,000 values only goes up to ~33,000,000.

Comment: @MarkAdler you are right, Thanks for pointing this out. I must have made a careless mistake when reporting the range. I have now edited the question to fix that. Hopefully, now my description is more accurately reflects that data I'm dealing with.

Comment: One thing still missing from the question is how the data will be used, why less than one GB would be a concern. Every mechanism mainly exploiting "the upper limit" will make more of a difference with just one million values than with 99. If you need "random access", you're better off with values reconstructible from a limited amount of data locatable somewhat rapidly. "increasing bit length" fits the bill nicely (storing the indexes where length needs to grow probably doesn't buy much), encoding value pairs until reaching 32 (or 31) bits closes (almost) half the gap to arithmetic coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to get better than a factor of two compression on your example data by using property 3, where I have taken property 3 to mean that every value must be less than its index, with the indices starting at 1. Simply use ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(*i*)) bits to store the number at index *i* (where *i* starts at 1). For your first example with 24,977 values, that compresses it of 43% of the size of the vector using 32-bit integers.

The number of bits required depends only on the length of the vector, *n*. The number of bits is:

1 - 2<sup>ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*))</sup> + *n* ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*))

As noted by Falk Hüffner, a simpler approach would be a fixed number of bits for all values of ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)). A variable number of bits will always be less than that, but not much less than that for large *n*.

If it is common to have a run of zeros at the start, then compress those with a count. There are only a handful of runs of two or three numbers in the remainder, so run-length encoding won't help except for that initial run of zeros.

Another 2% or so (for large sets) could be shaved off using an arithmetic coding approach, considering each value at index *k* (indices starting at zero) to be a base *k+1* digit of a very large integer. That would take ceiling(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*!)) bits.

Here is a plot of the compression ratios of the arithmetic coding, variable bits per sample coding, and fixed bits per sample coding, all ratioed to a representation with 32 bits for every sample (the sequence length is on a log scale):

[image: arithmetic better than variable better than fixed]

The arithmetic approach requires multiplication and division on integers the length of the compressed data, which is monumentally slow for large vectors. The code below limits the size of the integers to 64 bits, at some cost to the compression ratio, in exchange for it being very fast. This code will give compression ratios about 0.2% to 0.7% more than arithmetic in the plot above, well below variable bits. The data vector *must* have the property that each value is non-negative
and that each value is less than its position (positions starting at one).
The compression effectiveness depends *only* on that property, plus a small reduction if there is an initial run of zeros.
There appears to be a bit more redundancy in the provided examples that this
compression approach does not exploit.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

// Append val, as a variable-length integer, to comp. val must be non-negative.
template <typename T>
void write_varint(T val, std::vector<uint8_t>& comp) {
    while (val > 0x7f) {
        comp.push_back(val & 0x7f);
        val >>= 7;
    }
    comp.push_back(val | 0x80);
}

// Return the variable-length integer at offset off in comp, updating off to
// point after the integer.
template <typename T>
T read_varint(std::vector<uint8_t> const& comp, size_t& off) {
    T val = 0, next;
    int shift = 0;
    for (;;) {
        next = comp.at(off++);
        if (next > 0x7f)
            break;
        val |= next << shift;
        shift += 7;
    }
    val |= (next & 0x7f) << shift;
    return val;
}

// Given the starting index i >= 1, find the optimal number of values to code
// into 64 bits or less, or up through index n-1, whichever comes first.
// Optimal is defined as the least amount of entropy lost by representing the
// group in an integral number of bits, divided by the number of bits. Return
// the optimal number of values in num, and the number of bits needed to hold
// an integer representing that group in len.
static void group_ar64(size_t i, size_t n, size_t& num, int& len) {
    // Analyze all of the permitted groups, starting at index i.
    double min = 1.;
    uint64_t k = 1;                 // integer range is 0..k-1
    auto j = i + 1;
    do {
        k *= j;
        auto e = log2(k);           // entropy of k possible integers
        int b = ceil(e);            // number of bits to hold 0..k-1
        auto loss = (b - e) / b;    // unused entropy per bit
        if (loss < min) {
            num = j - i;            // best number of values so far
            len = b;                // bit length for that number
            if (loss == 0.)
                break;              // not going to get any better
            min = loss;
        }
    } while (j < n && k <= (uint64_t)-1 / ++j);
}

// Compress the data arithmetically coded as an incrementing base integer, but
// with a 64-bit limit on each integer. This puts values into groups that each
// fit in 64 bits, with the least amount of wasted entropy. Also compress the
// initial run of zeros into a count.
template <typename T>
std::vector<uint8_t> compress_ar64(std::vector<T> const& data) {
    // Resulting compressed data vector.
    std::vector<uint8_t> comp;

    // Start with number of values to make the stream self-terminating.
    write_varint(data.size(), comp);
    if (data.size() == 0)
        return comp;

    // Run-length code the initial run of zeros. Write the number of contiguous
    // zeros after the first one.
    size_t i = 1;
    while (i < data.size() && data[i] == 0)
        i++;
    write_varint(i - 1, comp);

    // Compress the data into variable-base integers starting at index i, where
    // each integer fits into 64 bits.
    unsigned buf = 0;       // output bit buffer
    int bits = 0;           // number of bits in buf (0..7)
    while (i < data.size()) {
        // Find the optimal number of values to code, starting at index i.
        size_t num;  int len;
        group_ar64(i, data.size(), num, len);

        // Code num values.
        uint64_t code = 0;
        size_t k = 1;
        do {
            code += k * data[i++];
            k *= i;
        } while (--num);

        // Write code using len bits.
        if (bits) {
            comp.push_back(buf | (code << bits));
            code >>= 8 - bits;
            len -= 8 - bits;
        }
        while (len > 7) {
            comp.push_back(code);
            code >>= 8;
            len -= 8;
        }
        buf = code;
        bits = len;
    }
    if (bits)
        comp.push_back(buf);
    return comp;
}

// Decompress the result of compress_ar64(), returning the original values.
// Start decompression at offset off in comp. When done, off is updated to
// point just after the compressed data.
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> expand_ar64(std::vector<uint8_t> const& comp, size_t& off) {
    // Will contain the uncompressed data to return.
    std::vector<T> data;

    // Get the number of values.
    auto vals = read_varint<size_t>(comp, off);
    if (vals == 0)
        return data;

    // Get the number of zeros after the first one, and write all of them.
    auto run = read_varint<size_t>(comp, off) + 1;
    auto i = run;
    do {
        data.push_back(0);
    } while (--run);

    // Extract the values from the compressed data starting at index i.
    unsigned buf = 0;       // input bit buffer
    int bits = 0;           // number of bits in buf (0..7)
    while (i < vals) {
        // Find the optimal number of values to code, starting at index i. This
        // simply repeats the same calculation that was done when compressing.
        size_t num;  int len;
        group_ar64(i, vals, num, len);

        // Read len bits into code.
        uint64_t code = buf;
        while (bits + 8 < len) {
            code |= (uint64_t)comp.at(off++) << bits;
            bits += 8;
        }
        len -= bits;                    // bits to pull from last byte (1..8)
        uint64_t last = comp.at(off++); // last byte
        code |= (last & ((1 << len) - 1)) << bits;
        buf = last >> len;              // save remaining bits in buffer
        bits = 8 - len;

        // Extract num values from code.
        do {
            i++;
            data.push_back(code % i);
            code /= i;
        } while (--num);
    }

    // Return the uncompressed data.
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how exploiting property 3 would save that much; e.g. in the second half of the data it would save at most a single bit per value compared to using a fixed number of bits. And if I compare this idea to just using a fixed 32 bit (`sum(ceil(log2(i)) for i in range(1, 100_000_000)) / sum(32 for i in range(1, 100_000_000))`) indeed it's only 20% smaller, and most of that comes from the fact that these numbers all would have fit into less than 32 bits; using a fixed 25 bits from observing that the maximum value is 33,000,000 would shrink the data more.

Comment: @FalkHüffner Because the questioner says they are using 32-bit integers to store each value, and the example data provided by the questioner has 24,977 values. The total number of bits, summing the ceiling of the logs, is then 341,888 bits, or 10,684 32-bit words. As compared to 24,977 32-bit words. Yes, the questioner could have stored that data in 16-bit words, in which case this approach would only compress it down to 86% of the original size.

Comment: @FalkHüffner No, a fixed number of bits will never shrink the data more. 33,000,000 values would take 791,445,569 bits using the variable length approach, whereas it would take 825,000,000 bits at 25 bits each. About 4% more.

Comment: Mark Adler, Thanks for your explanation. As @FalkHüffner noted, and as you have shown in your plot, this will have a good effect if my vector length was smaller. However, since I'm dealing with vector lengths up to 100 million elements this does seem to be less effective for my data. I'm now trying to decompose the the 32-bit vector into 4x8-bit vectors to see if the smaller valued vectors are more compressible. Please see my Edit for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the new plot! This looks more promising than the previous one which was hard to infer the compression ratio from it. I'm generally dealing with variable sized vectors and as I see from this plot, the compression ratio looks good for vector sizes that are less than 1 million elements. Also, I haven't implemented variable bits before so it will be very helpful if you can direct me toward a working C++ implementation or a free library so that I can use the method for the smaller sized vectors. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As I suggested in my comment you can represent your data as 8bit. There are simple ways on how to do it efficiently no need for modular arithmetics..

You can use union or pointers for this so for example in C++ if you have:

```
unsigned int data32[]={0,0,0,...};
unsigned char *data08=data32;
```

Or you can copy it to 4 BYTE array but that will be slower.

If you have to use modular arithmetics for any reasons then you might want to do it like this:

```
 x     &255
(x>> 8)&255
(x>>16)&255
(x>>24)&255
```

Now [I have tried LZW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62100123/2521214) on your new data and the compression ratio result without any data reordering (single LZW) was 81-82% (depending on dictionary size I suggest to use 10bit LZW dictionary) which is not as good as expected. So I reordered the data into 4 arrays (just like you did) so first array has lowest 8bits and last the highest. The results with 12 bit dictionary where:

```
ratio08: 144%
ratio08: 132%
ratio08:  26%
ratio08:   0%
total:    75%
```

The results with 10 bit dictionary where:

```
ratio08: 123%
ratio08: 117%
ratio08:  28%
ratio08:   0%
total:    67%
```

Showing that LZW is bad for lowest bytes (and with increasing size it will be worse for higher bytes too) So use it only for the higher BYTEs which would improve the compress ratio more.

However I expect huffman should lead to much better results so [I computed entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785375/2521214) for your data:

```
H32 = 5.371071 , H/8 = 0.671384
H08 = 7.983666 , H/8 = 0.997958
H08 = 7.602564 , H/8 = 0.950321
H08 = 1.902525 , H/8 = 0.237816
H08 = 0.000000 , H/8 = 0.000000
total: 54%
```

meaning naive single huffman encoding would have compress ratio 67% and the separate 4 arrays would lead to 54% which is much better so in your case I would go for **huffman encoding**. After I implemented it here the result:

```
[Huffman]
ratio08 =  99.992%
ratio08 =  95.400%
ratio08 =  24.706%
ratio08 =   0.000%
total08 =  55.025%
ratio32 =  67.592%
```

Which closely matches the estimation by Shannon entropy as expected (not accounting the decoding table) ...

However with very big datasets I expect naive huffman will start to get slightly better than the separate 4x huffman ...

Also note that the result where truncated so those 0% are not zero but something less than 1% ...

**[Edit1] 300 000 000 entries estimation**

so to simulate the conditions for 300M 32bit numbers of yours I use 16bit numbers sub part of your data with similar "empty space" properties.

```
log2(300 000 000) = ~28
28/32 * 16 = 14
```

so I use only 2^14 16bit numbers which should have similar properties as your 300M 32 bit numbers The 8bit Huffman encoding leads to:

```
ratio08 =  97.980%
ratio08 =  59.534%
total08 =  78.757%
```

So I estimate 80% ratio between encoded/decoded sizes ~1.25 size reduction.
(Hope I did not screw something up with my assumptions).

Answer (score 5):

Solving every compression problem should begin with an analysis.

I looked at the raw data file containing the first 24976 values. The smallest value is 0 and the largest is 24950. The "slope" of the data is then around 1. However, It should decrease over time, if the maximum is, as told, only 33M@100M values. Assumption of slope=1 is then a bit pessimistic.

As for the distribution,

```
tr '[,]' '[\n]' <compression.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n256
```

produces

```
164  0
131  8
111  1648
108  1342
104  725
103  11
 91  1475
 90  1446
 82  21
 82  1355
 78  69
 76  2
 75  12
 72  328
 71  24
 70  614
 70  416
 70  1608
 70  1266
 69  22
 67  356
 67  3
 66  1444
 65  19
 65  1498
 65  10
 64  2056
 64  16
 64  1322
 64  1182
 63  249
 63  1335
 61  43
 60  17
 60  1469
 59  33
 59  3116
 58  20
 58  1201
 57  303
 55  5
 55  4
 55  2559
 55  1324
 54  1110
 53  1984
 53  1357
 52  807
 52  56
 52  4321
 52  2892
 52  1
 50  39
 50  2475
 49  1580
 48  664
 48  266
 47  317
 47  1255
 46  981
 46  37
 46  3531
 46  23
 43  1923
 43  1248
 41  396
 41  2349
 40  7
 39  6
 39  54
 39  4699
 39  32
 38  815
 38  2006
 38  194
 38  1298
 38  1284
 37  44
 37  1550
 37  1369
 37  1273
 36  1343
 35  61
 35  3991
 35  3606
 35  1818
 35  1701
 34  836
 34  27
 34  264
 34  241
 34  1306
 33  821
 33  28
 33  248
 33  18
 33  15
 33  1017
 32  9
 32  68
 32  53
 32  240
 32  1516
 32  1474
 32  1390
 32  1312
 32  1269
 31  667
 31  326
 31  263
 31  25
 31  160
 31  1253
 30  3365
 30  2082
 30  18550
 30  1185
 30  1049
 30  1018
 29  73
 29  487
 29  48
 29  4283
 29  34
 29  243
 29  1605
 29  1515
 29  1470
 29  1297
 29  1183
 28  980
 28  60
 28  302
 28  242
 28  1959
 28  1779
 28  161
 27  811
 27  51
 27  36
 27  201
 27  1270
 27  1267
 26  979
 26  50
 26  40
 26  3111
 26  26
 26  2425
 26  1807
 25  825
 25  823
 25  812
 25  77
 25  46
 25  217
 25  1842
 25  1831
 25  1534
 25  1464
 25  1321
 24  730
 24  66
 24  59
 24  427
 24  355
 24  1465
 24  1299
 24  1164
 24  1111
 23  941
 23  892
 23  7896
 23  663
 23  607
 23  556
 23  47
 23  2887
 23  251
 23  1776
 23  1583
 23  1488
 23  1349
 23  1244
 22  82
 22  818
 22  661
 22  42
 22  411
 22  3337
 22  3190
 22  3028
 22  30
 22  2226
 22  1861
 22  1363
 22  1301
 22  1262
 22  1158
 21  74
 21  49
 21  41
 21  376
 21  354
 21  2156
 21  1688
 21  162
 21  1453
 21  1067
 21  1053
 20  711
 20  413
 20  412
 20  38
 20  337
 20  2020
 20  1897
 20  1814
 20  17342
 20  173
 20  1256
 20  1160
 19  9169
 19  83
 19  679
 19  4120
 19  399
 19  2306
 19  2042
 19  1885
 19  163
 19  1623
 19  1380
 18  805
 18  79
 18  70
 18  6320
 18  616
 18  455
 18  4381
 18  4165
 18  3761
 18  35
 18  2560
 18  2004
 18  1900
 18  1670
 18  1546
 18  1291
 18  1264
 18  1181
 17  824
 17  8129
 17  63
 17  52
 17  5138
```

as the most frequent 256 values.

It seems some values are inherently more common. When examined, those common values also seem to be distributed all over the data.

I propose the following:

Divide the data into blocks. For each block, send the actual value of the slope, so when coding each symbol we know its maximum value.

Code the common values in a block with statistical coding (Huffman etc.). In this case, the cutoff with an alphabet of 256 would be around 17 occurrences.

For less common values, we reserve a small part of the alphabet for sending the amount of bits in the value.

When we encounter a rare value, its bits are coded without statistical modeling. The topmost bit can be omitted, since we know it's always 1 (unless value is '0').

Usually the range of values to be coded is not a power-of-2. For example, if we have 10 choices, this requires 4 bits to code, but there are 6 unused bit patterns - sometimes we only need 3 bits. The first 6 choices we code directly with 3 bits. If it's 7 or 8, we send an extra bit to indicate if we meant 9 or 10.

Additionally, we could exclude any value that is directly coded from the list of possible values. Otherwise we have two ways to code the same value, which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are dealing with is "nearly" sorted, so you can use that to great effect with delta encoding.

A simple approach is as follows:

Look for runs of data, denoted by `R_i = (v,l,N)` where `l` is the length of the run, `N` is the bit-depth needed to do delta encoding on the sorted run, and `v` is the value of the first element of the (sorted) run (needed for delta encoding.) The run itself then just needs to store 2 pieces of information for each entry in the run: the idx of each sorted element in the run and the delta. Note, to store the idx of each sorted element, only `log_2(l)` bits are needed per idx, where `l` is the length of the run.

The encoding works by attempting to find the least number of bits to fully encode the run when compared to the number of bytes used in its uncompressed form. In practice, this can be implemented by finding the longest run that is encoded for a fixed number of bytes per element.

To decode, simply decode run-by-run (in order) first decoding the delta coding/compression, then undoing the sort.

Here is some C++ code that computes the compression ratio that can be obtained using this scheme on the data sample you posted. The implementation takes a greedy approach in selecting the runs, it is possible slightly better results are available if a smarter approach is used.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

#include "data.h"

template <int _N, int _M> struct T {
  constexpr static int N = _N;
  constexpr static int M = _M;
  uint16_t idx : N;
  uint16_t delta : M;
};

template <int _N, int _M>
std::pair<int32_t, int32_t> best_packed_run_stats(size_t idx) {
  const int N = 1 << _N;
  const int M = 1 << _M;
  static std::vector<int32_t> buffer(N);
  if (idx + N >= data.size())
    return {-1, 0};
  std::copy(&data[idx], &data[idx + N], buffer.data());
  std::sort(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
  int32_t run_len = 0;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i, ++run_len) {
    auto delta = buffer[i] - buffer[i - 1];
    assert(delta >= 0);
    if (delta >= M) {
      break;
    }
  }
  int32_t savings = run_len * (sizeof(int32_t) - sizeof(T<_N, _M>)) -
                    1    // 1 byte to store bit-depth
                    - 2; // 2 bytes to store run length
  return {savings, run_len};
}

template <class... Args>
std::vector<std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>> all_runs_stats(size_t idx) {
  return {best_packed_run_stats<Args::N, Args::M>(idx)...};
}

int main() {

  size_t total_savings = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    auto runs =
        all_runs_stats<T<2, 14>, T<4, 12>, T<8, 8>, T<12, 4>, T<14, 2>>(i);
    auto best_value = *std::max_element(runs.begin(), runs.end());
    total_savings += best_value.first;
    i += best_value.second;
  }
  size_t uncomp_size = data.size() * sizeof(int32_t);
  double comp_ratio =
      (uncomp_size - (double)total_savings) / (double)uncomp_size;
  printf("uncomp_size: %lu\n", uncomp_size);
  printf("compression: %lf\n", comp_ratio);
  printf("size: %lu\n", data.size());
}
```

Note, only certain fixed configurations of 16-bit representations of elements in a run are attempted. Because of this we should expect the best possible compression we can achieve is `50%` (i.e. 4 bytes -> 2 bytes.) In reality, there is overhead.

This code when run on the data sample you supplied reports this compression ration:

```
uncomp_size: 99908
compression: 0.505785
size: 24977
```

which is very close to the theoretical limit of `.5` for this compression algorithm.

Also, note, that this slightly beats out the Shannon entropy estimate reported in another answer.

---

Edit to address Mark Adler's comment below.

Re-running this compression on the larger data-set provided (compression2.txt) along with comparing to Mark Adler's approach here are the results:

```
uncomp_size: 2602628
compression: 0.507544
size: 650657
bit compression: 0.574639
```

Where `bit compression` is the compression ratio of Mark Adler's approach. As noted by others, compressing the bits of each entry will not scale well for large data, we should expect the ratio to get worse with `n`.

Meanwhile the delta + sorting compression described above maintains close to its theoretical best of `.5`.

Comment: I got 0.426522 for that sequence by simply storing each value in the number of bits its index takes, and doing run-length coding on the initial sequence of zeros. Or 0.411469 storing it as a single, large variable-base integer.

Comment: @MarkAdler I've updated my answer showing that the approach you suggest will scale poorly with `n` (as previously pointed out by others.) Meanwhile, this approach maintains close to its theoretical limit (give its construction.)

Comment: Your calculation of integral-bits-per-value approach is wrong and over-optimistic somehow. That should be 0.574639. When I include run-length encoding of the initial zeros, I get 0.573940. Arithmetic coding gives 0.558403.

Comment: @MarkAdler: you are correct, I was using floor(log_2(i)) instead of ceil(log_2(i)), I will update results.

Comment: I am not seeing where you account for the bits to store `v` for each run.

Comment: `V` doesn't have to be accounted for in the `savings` as it requires 4 bytes in the original representation and 4 bytes in the new representation (i.e. no change.) However, its idx in the sorted list does need to be accounted for.

Comment: Ah, I see. `run_len` doesn't include the first element of the run.

Comment: As requested, I have now provided around 11 million elements of a similar data (The Link at the end of my post - Edit3). The data follows the same pattern as before except this time there is an initial padding of -1s instead of 0s (the initial padding is too small compared to the size of the vector, hence, it is not important and it will be discarded anyway. All other values are positive)

Comment: Looks like ldog's scheme on 11 million values with a ratio of 0.6846 still does better than the variable integral bits per value at 0.7048. Also a smidge better than 0.6882 for the arithmetic approach.

Comment: I took the 11+ million values and wrote it out as four streams of bytes, one for each byte of the four-byte values. (I could have done three, but the result is about the same.) I then took that and compressed it with xz. The result is a compression ratio of 0.644778. So there is the possibility of some gain beyond compression using only property #3.