# Not able to understand an SO answer on compressing and decompressing a sorted list of integers using this custom scheme

Tags: c++, compression

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944724/4045121) and I am not sure I understand how it works. Specifically, the bulk of the original values are encoded using this code:

```
// Code num values.
uint64_t code = 0;
size_t k = 1;
do {
  code += k * data[i++];
  k *= i;
} while (--num);
```

And then the claim is that the code below will give the original values back:

```
// Extract num values from code.
do {
  i++;
  data.push_back(code % i);
  code /= i;
} while (--num);
```

But, I'm not sure I understand how that is possible. If we run this with some random data, eg:

`d = [8, 18, 36]`

then we would have:

**Encoding**

```
k   d[1]     Code
-----------------
1 * 8  = 8   8
2 * 18 = 36  44
6 * 36 = 216 260
```

I'm not sure how I will get the original data back using the suggested procedure, though.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to read the entire answer. In particular, the assumption at the start of my answer, which comes from the OP:

> every value must be less than its index, with the indices starting at
> 1

Your example does not meet that constraint.